# SP2013 CopyIntoItems not creating thumbnails

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, picture-library, image-upload

I am uploading images to custom list, using `CopyIntoItems`, which has only one content type derived from `Picture`. Images are being uploaded successfully, however neither Thumbnail nor Preview are generated. I have tried the approach with invoking the `/_t/pic_jpg.jpg` URL but it's not working (gives me err. 404).

How to generate image thumbnails after programmatic upload?

Comment: If anyone need a workaround: creating an `Item Added` `Event Receiver` which sets `properties.ListItem[SPBuiltInFieldId.AlternateThumbnailUrl] = (string)properties.ListItem.File.Item[SPBuiltInFieldId.EncodedAbsUrl]` does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the Picture content type it does not have an thumbnail preview column in the content type.  The Image content type does have a thumbnail preview column.  Try adding the Image content type to your library.  It should generate the thumbnail preview for you.

Comment: I don't have 'Image' content type. Skimming through my farm with SharePoint Manager, I can see 'Thumbnail' and 'Preview' fields in 'Picture' content type. Can it be because I'm using WSS?

Comment: Hmm that is weird.  My Picture content type does not have thumbnail.  Only preview and preview URL.  Note sure about the difference.  What Version are you running?  I have MOSS 2013 15.0.4420.1017

Comment: I have WSS 2013 15.0.4420.1017

Comment: Sorry. I typed the wrong version.  I am at 15.0.4517.1005.  Maybe that is the reason for the discrepancy in our content types.  Can you post your code?  Maybe I can see how it works on my VM?